# How do i change the .htaccess on cPanel's Online File Manager (ByetHost)?

Tags: .htaccess, file-manager

I'm using ByetHost as my website's FTP service, i configure everything (besides uploading the stuff) via ByetHost's Vista Panel, which has a Online File Manager where i presume i could edit the .htaccess.
However when i arrive at the File Manager, i can't seem to find the .htaccess file, and there is also a lack of a Settings button too.
Here is what the File Manager looks like: (the htdocs is where all my website's stuff is at)
[image]
I know ByetHost and/or whatever this unknown File Manager is not well known, but i'd like to ask anyways if there's anyone that could help me on how to configure my .htaccess. I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue too, and couldn't find any settings or otherwise.

So what I simply did was:

Just created a new file and named it `.htaccess`!

And a quick test, I put in the following to allow access to my `.html` pages without actually typing the extension:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.html [NC,END]
```

And it worked successfully.

Comment: Can't believe i got my answer a full year later. Thanks.

Comment: Did you figure it out before this or use a different host? I just took a stab in the dark and created my own and it worked, as I couldn’t find the settings either and it wasn’t practical for me to change host provider. I edited the title for other users in the future also.

Comment: I switched to ProFreeHost due to it having faster video bandwidth. The .htaccess file was easily accessible via FileZilla.